# Octave- looping error

Tags: for-loop, syntax-error, octave

I'm doing ML from Cousera and it's producing an error for linear regression assignment and I don't understand what's the problem. I'm using octave 4.0 on windows 10. Here's the code:

```matlab
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)
  m         = length(y); % number of training examples
  hypo      = [m,1];
  J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);

  for iter = 1: num_iters

    % ====================== YOUR CODE HERE ======================
    % Instructions: Perform a single gradient step on the parameter vector
    %               theta. 
    %
    % Hint: While debugging, it can be useful to print out the values
    %       of the cost function (computeCost) and gradient here.
    %

    hypo  = theta(1) + theta(2) * X;
    temp1 = theta(1) - alpha * (1 / m) * sum(hypo);

    hypo  = theta(1) + theta(2) * X;
    temp2 = theta(2) - alpha * (1 / m) * sum((hypo .* X));  

    theta = [temp1; temp2];
    % ===========================================================

    % Save the cost J in every iteration    
    J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta);

  end

  predict1 = [1, 3.5] * theta;
  predict2 = [1, 7.0] * theta;

end
```

it's producing a looping error "A(I)= X:X same size as I" at

```matlab
 J_history(iters) = computeCost(X, y, theta);
```

Comment: What does `computeCost` return?

Comment: I think you mean matlab and not [ML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_%28programming_language%29).

Comment: @carandraug no I think coursera is actually offering a [Maching Learning course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning) and the main instructor (Andrew Ng) seems to recommend Octave from what I've heard. (Woo! \o/). I've seen a few people in the last couple of weeks quoting they've just installed Octave because they're doing the Andrew Ng course :)

Comment: He means that ML and MATLAB are two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discussing code of the course exercises is discouraged, so I wont fix this for you. I'll just give you a pointer.

`computeCost` expects `theta` to be of size 2,1, while the `theta` you post as argument is of size 2,2. Use the command `keyboard` to break/pause the execution on a specific line, and enter into a console session to debug. Check the dimensionality of the variables you post. You can resume the execution with `dbcont`.